# jQuery append text in but in a new line but br tag not working

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    $ ('.groupingRows')[0].append("Seleziona Bronze");
    $ ('.groupingRows')[2].append('hello2');
});
```

How to show "Seleziona Bronze" in new line as br tag not working

Comment: please post your markup and explain what you mean by "br tag not working"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get first and third .groupingRows

This is how you do that:

```
$('.groupingRows').eq(0);

$('.groupingRows').eq(2);
```

Then you append your text:

```
$('.groupingRows').eq(0).append("<br> Seleziona Bronze");
```

You can add as many br as you want.
Try this!